# Dynamic sequence in R

Tags: r, sequence

I just started with programming in R and have to write the number sequence 5, 25, 125, 625, 3125 in a vector with the function seq().

My idea is to do it like
 `x <- c(seq(from = 5, length = 5, by = ??))`.

I can't write a constant value to "by = ??", as the difference between two numbers are always changing.
The next value is always the previous value multiplied with 5.
Is there a way to take the previous number and multiply it with 5 in the sequence function?
Thanks!

Comment: @akrun's solution is equivalent to `5^seq(from = 1, to = 5)` if you really need to use `seq`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may do `^` and this gets the output

```
5^(1:5)
```

-output

```
[1]    5   25  125  625 3125
```